# Data Structure issues powershell

Tags: powershell

My end goal is to be able to enter several strings, then reference them in other commands, in this case, mapping a network drive.

I'm having issues with the 'several' part of that. I can work with one at a time, but when I try to do more it fails.

```
$Servers = @{"Server1" = "10.10.10.10";"Server2" = "10.10.10.11"}
$Sites = Read-Host "enter site codes"
$Sites.Split('.')
ForEach ($Site In Sites){
write-host $Servers[$Sites]
}
```

This in theory should output 10.10.10.10 and 10.10.10.11 on two lines, but it doesn't. It just outputs the value of $Sites, Server1,Server2

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mistake(s) is using $Sites (instead of $Site) as the key in your foreach loop, and not getting your split array into the foreach collection:

```
$Servers = @{"Server1" = "10.10.10.10";"Server2" = "10.10.10.11"}
$Sites = Read-Host "enter site codes"
ForEach ($Site In $Sites.Split(',')){
write-host $Servers[$Site]
}
```

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.  DAMHIKT.